# Doctrine DQL instance of for multi table inheritance entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, multiple-inheritance, dql

I have set up Doctrine multi table inheritance on my application - see below

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({
 *  "news" = "News" ,
 *  "press_release" = "PressRelease"})
 *
 * @table(name="pages")
 */
class PressRelease extends Page {...}
class News extends Page {...}
```

My custom repository query

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyStoreBundle:User u
LEFT JOIN u.page p
WHERE p INSTANCE OF :newsType'
)->setParameter('newsType', new News());
```

I thought this would work, however I keep getting the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /path/to/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php line 282
```

Obviously my `News` entity doesnt have an `id` field as this is inherited when extending the `Page` class which has the `id` property defined, does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

INSTANCE OF expects the entity class name, not an instance:

```
->setParameter('newsType', 'YourProject\News');
```

Comment: I think it will be escaped and will not work. Do not bind it as a parameter. Put it like this `$qb->where($qb->expr()->isInstanceOf('p', 'YourProject\News'));`

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine sets all properties to private. So you can not access those from an inherited class.
You can set the `private` properties in the parent class to `protected`. I guess it will work then.

Comment: I thought this might be case, however i've changed the parent class properties to `protected` and it still doesnt work, i've debugged this further and it seems like the `Doctrine Class Metadata` doesnt pick up thats its a extended entity, therefore doesnt recognise the parent ID property